# Subset all rows in a dataframe that are NOT unique (based on a vector/column) .. or remove unique rows

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, unique

I have a dataframe with many genes (the column being "gene"). Some of the genes appear more than once. I want to subset the dataframe where I only have genes that appear MORE than once. In other words, I want to REMOVE the rows that are unique in respect to the "gene" column.

Answer (score 5):

We can use `subset` with `table` in `base R`.  Get the frequency count of 'genes' with `table`, create a logical expression that checks the count greater than 1, retrieve those genes and use `%in%` to subset those genes

```
subset(df1, genes %in% names(which(table(genes) > 1)))
```

---

Or another option is `duplicated`

```
subset(df1, duplicated(genes)|duplicated(genes, fromLast = TRUE))
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(genes) %>%
   filter(n() > 1) %>%
   ungroup
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option, using `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(df, ave(gene,gene,FUN = length)>1)
```